# FileSaver.js doesnt download pdf/excel in IOS devices

Tags: ios, angular, filesaver.js

I have been using FileSaver.js to download *PDF/Excel* attachments. While this approach works in all other devices , I am not able to download the attachment in iOS devices 10+.

```
const wbout: string = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
saveAs(new Blob([wbout],{type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'}), "My List" + '.xlsx');
```

I dont want to open the attachment in a new tab — rather, it should do its normal functionality, i.e. download the file.

I have referred this https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/375 but still couldnt find a fix.

Comment: Which version are you using ? Try to install the latest version of FileSaver - 1.3.8

Comment: I have been using v1.3.0 , will update it and verify once

Comment: Didnt work out mate